# What does this statement in ruby mean?

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and didn't understand what this statement does.

```
dependency 'multi_json'
```

More info: https://github.com/vongrippen/bitbucket/blob/master/lib/bitbucket_rest_api/request/jsonize.rb#L11

Any ruby experts, help please.

Comment: Perhaps giving more context like were you encounter that? an error? bundle error? would help ppl help you better

Comment: @Nimir https://github.com/vongrippen/bitbucket/blob/master/lib/bitbucket_rest_api/request/jsonize.rb#L11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sends the message `dependency` to the implicit receiver `self` passing the `String` `'multi_json'` as the only argument.

By the way: it's not a statement, it's an expression. Everything in Ruby is an expression, there are no statements.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a core ruby method. It comes from the parent class **Faraday::Middleware**

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/middleware.rb#L12

Here is the implementation:

```
# Executes a block which should try to require and reference dependent libraries
def self.dependency(lib = nil)
  lib ? require(lib) : yield
rescue LoadError, NameError => error
  self.load_error = error
end
```

So what it basically do is trying to require the argument lib, in your case the `'multi-json'` library.